# Cliente Netty se detiene despues de horas o dias

Tags: java, spring-boot

Java 1.8

spring-boot-starter-parent 2.3.2.RELEASE

spring-webflux 5.2.8.RELEASE

spring-boot-starter-reactor-netty 2.3.2.RELEASE

La aplicacion se ejecuta sobre WebSphere Application Server 9

Mi aplicación es un cliente Netty con soporte de re conexión que lee los datos que se envían a un socket. Se toman los datos y se buscan los delimitadores de inicio y fin del frame, una vez que lo encuentra, lo envía al siguiente handler que procesa la información. Después de varios días o solo horas el cliente deja de capturar los datos que se envían al socket, observando el archivo de registro el único error es:

`2020-08-13 15: 31: 34,885 ERROR [nioEventLoopGroup-2-1] i.n.u.ResourceLeakDetector [?:?] LEAK: ByteBuf.release () was not called before garbage collection`

Main class

```
public void run() {
        LOGGER.info("Levantando la aplicacion CAPTURADOR");
        closed = false;
        workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        bootstrap = new Bootstrap();
        bootstrap.group(workerGroup);
        bootstrap.channel(NioSocketChannel.class);
        bootstrap.handler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
            @Override
            protected void initChannel(SocketChannel socketChannel) throws Exception {
                ChannelPipeline pipeline = socketChannel.pipeline();
                pipeline.addFirst(new ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void channelInactive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
                        super.channelInactive(ctx);
                        ctx.channel().eventLoop().schedule(() -> doConnect(), 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                    }
                });
                socketChannel.pipeline().addLast(frameExtractor);
                socketChannel.pipeline().addLast(new LoggingHandler("SERVER_LOG", LogLevel.valueOf(logLevel)));
                socketChannel.pipeline().addLast(clientHandler);
            }
        });
        doConnect();
    }

    /**
     *
     */
    private void doConnect() {
        if (closed) {
            return;
        }
        ChannelFuture future = bootstrap.connect(new InetSocketAddress(remoteHost, remotePort));
        future.addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
            @Override
            public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture f) throws Exception {
                if (f.isSuccess()) {
                    LOGGER.info("Started Tcp Client: " + getServerInfo());
                } else {
                    LOGGER.error("Started Tcp Client Failed: " + getServerInfo());
                    f.channel().eventLoop().schedule(() -> doConnect(), 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

FrameExtractor class - toma las tramas y detecta inicio y fin

```
/**
     * En el método channelActive() que es al que nos llama netty cuando el canal de comunicación está activo,
     * aprovechamos para crear el buffer que mencionamos.
     */
    @Override
    public void channelRegistered(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        buf = ctx.alloc().buffer();
    }

    /**
     * En el metodo channelInactive() que es al que nos llama netty cuando el canal de comunicación deja de estar
     * activo, aprovechamos para liberar el buffer que creamos @channelRegistered.
     */
    @Override
    public void channelUnregistered(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        if (null != buf) {
            buf.release();
            buf = null;
        }

    }

 /**
     * Arma el envio de la medicion buscando el fin de trama y lo pasa al siguiente handler
     */
    @Override
    public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
        try {
            Level level = ResourceLeakDetector.getLevel();
            // El msg que recibimos como parametro es un ByteBuf de Netty. Añadimos todo su contenido al final de
            // nuestro ByteBuf buf para ir acumulando el envio de bytes hasta que se encuentre el fin de envio de trama
            buf.writeBytes((ByteBuf) msg);

            String data = buf.toString(Charset.defaultCharset());

            int indexOf1 = indexOf(buf, Directlink.DELIMETER_DIRECTLINK, 1);
            int indexOf2 = indexOf(buf, Directlink.DELIMETER_DIRECTLINK, 2);

            while (-1 != indexOf2) {
                // Creamos un nuevo ByteBuf para copiar la trama hasta el indicador del fin de trama
                ByteBuf line = ctx.alloc().buffer();
                line = buf.copy(indexOf1, indexOf2 - indexOf1);
                // Agregamos al buffer buf todos los bytes hasta el indicador de fin de trama
                buf.readBytes(indexOf2);
                // Avisamos al siguiente handler, pasandole nuestro buffer line. No liberamos el buffer line porque es
                // responsabilidad del que lo recibe.
                ctx.fireChannelRead(line);
                buf.discardReadBytes();
                indexOf1 = indexOf(buf, Directlink.DELIMETER_DIRECTLINK, 1);
                indexOf2 = indexOf(buf, Directlink.DELIMETER_DIRECTLINK, 2);
            }
        } finally {
            // Liberamos el buffer que nos ha llegado por parametro. Como ya no lo necesitamos y no se lo hemos pasado a
            // nadie es nuestra responsabilidad liberarlo.
            ReferenceCountUtil.release(msg);
        }
    }
```

ClientHandler class

```
 public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
        ByteBuf buffer = ctx.alloc().buffer();
        try {
            buffer.writeBytes((ByteBuf) msg);
            byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.readableBytes()];
            int readerIndex = buffer.readerIndex();
            buffer.getBytes(readerIndex, bytes);
            bytes = CapturadorUtils.eliminarParidad(bytes);
            String trama = new String(bytes);
            CapturadorGenerico capturadorGenerico = trama.contains(Directlink.KEY_DIRECTLINK)
                    ? capturadorFactory.getCapturador(Directlink.getDirectlink())
                            : capturadorFactory.getCapturador(Microcom.MICROCOM);
                    capturadorGenerico.parsearTrama(trama, bytes);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("Error producido en el pipe ClientHandler con la trama: " + msg, e);
        } finally {
            // Liberamos el buffer que nos ha llegado por parametro. Como ya no lo necesitamos y no se lo hemos pasado a
            // nadie es nuestra responsabilidad liberarlo.
            ReferenceCountUtil.release(msg);
            ReferenceCountUtil.release(buffer);
        }
    }
```

Revisando el código y analizando la documentación https://netty.io/wiki/reference-counted-objects.html no encontré cuál podría ser el error. Los buffers se liberan correctamente.

Log file

```
2020-08-14 11:23:30,404 ERROR [nioEventLoopGroup-2-1] i.n.u.ResourceLeakDetector [?:?] LEAK: ByteBuf.release() was not called before it's garbage-collected. See http://netty.io/wiki/reference-counted-objects.html for more information.
Recent access records: 
Created at:
    io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator.newDirectBuffer(PooledByteBufAllocator.java:349)
    io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBufAllocator.directBuffer(AbstractByteBufAllocator.java:187)
    io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBufAllocator.directBuffer(AbstractByteBufAllocator.java:173)
    io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBufAllocator.buffer(AbstractByteBufAllocator.java:107)
    cl.mop.dga.satelital.capturador.handler.FrameExtractor.channelRead(FrameExtractor.java:76)
    io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374)
    io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360)
    io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
    io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1408)
    io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374)
    io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360)
    io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:930)
    io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163)
    io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:682)
    io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:617)
    io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:534)
    io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:496)
    io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:906)
    io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:785)
```

El error lo marca en las lineas:

ByteBuf line = ctx.alloc().buffer();

line = buf.copy(indexOf1, indexOf2 - indexOf1);

Agregue en la clase principal la línea ResourceLeakDetector.setLevel (Level.PARANOID) pero el log no cambió. También trate de configurarlo desde jvm -Dio.netty.leakDetectionLevel = PARANOID pero no pude conseguir que me mostrara un mayor nivel de detalle. Estoy usando logback.

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente resolví el error modificando el ultimo handler del pipeline y para cada trama obtenida creo un thread y lo envio a continuar con el procesamiento propio de la aplicación, parsing, inserción en base de datos, etc.
Tal vez Netty maneje algún mecanismo de prevención en el manejo de los buffers y al demorar el procesamiento el buffer que iba almacenando las tramas hasta identificar el inicio y fin de las mismas se llenaba.
Quiero resaltar que el error que tenia originalmente en el manejo del buffer lo pudo solucionar con el consejo de @NormanMaurer
"readBytes (...) devolverá un nuevo ByteBuf que debe liberar una vez que haya terminado de usar. Lo más probable es que desee utilizar skipBytes (...) en su caso de uso"